# How to stub multiple method calls in OCMockito

Tags: objective-c, unit-testing, ocmockito

I am trying to unit test a method that calls the same method on a mocked object multiple times.  In Java, using Mockito, I could provide multiple results to return from the method:

```
when(mock.someMethod()).thenReturn(1,1,0);
```

I would like to do the same for OCMockito if possible. Something like:

```
[given([mock someMethod]) willReturn:@1,@1,0];
```

Thanks for any input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OCMockito doesn't support that at this time. Feel free to submit a new issue with a feature request.

In the meantime, you may want to use a hand-rolled mock to accomplish what you need.